# How Can I Put a Dictionary Inside An Array That's Nested In Another Dictionary? (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, nested

I want to add an array of dictionaries to an existing dictionary.

```
var details: [String : [String : String]] = [:]
viewDidLoad()
...
    for i in 0..<count {
        let hour = makeHourString()
        details[hour] = [String: String] () as [String : String]
        let dict = ["detailKey": "2100xx", "detailImage":"base64xx"]
        details[hour].append(dict)
    }
...
```

It is telling me: Value of type '[String : String]' has no member 'append.' But shouldn't it since it's an array?

I can get this kind of nested dictionary if I change the code to:

```
var details: [String: [Any]] = [:]
viewDidLoad()
...
    for i in 0..<count {
        let hour = makeHourString()
        details[hour] = [String] () as [String]
        let dict = ["detailKey": "2100xx", "detailImage":"base64xx"]
        details[hour].append(dict)
    }
...
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working for me because I need to able to store my data source using Codable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `for _ in 0..<count { details[makeHourString()] = ["detailKey": "2100xx", "detailImage":"base64xx"] }`

Comment: Or if you want an array `for _ in 0..<count { details[makeHourString()] = [["detailKey": "2100xx", "detailImage":"base64xx"]] }`

Comment: I like how you just use the makeHourString method right in the index. For some reason I am paranoid about doing that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `[String : String]` is a `Dictionary` not an `Array` , According to your case you need

```
var details: [String: [[String:String]]] = [:]
```

and off course you can do this also

```
var details: [String:[Item]] = [:]
```

With

```
struct Item {
   let detailKey, detailImage:String
}
```

Comment: Ugh. I was trying it without the extra nested array when making the key. This works: details[time] = [[String: String]] () as [[String: String]] and you helped me figure it out. God bless you.

Comment: @Lester the cast (`as ...`) is not needed.